# Excel dynamic chart from a Pivot Table and static data

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts

I have data for three years. This years data 15/16 is updating each week. The previous two years data is complete and is static (no longer updating).

I can make a chart with all three years on a different series but I have to manually change the range each week to update the chart.

How can I make a chart that will map the two previous years and the current weekly data to one chart. Pulling data from this years pivot and the weekly totals from the last two years which are static data?

Thanks

Update:

After trying the suggestion to add "=iferror" as blank ("") the graph plots the rest of the year but the future dates appear as 0 on the graph, how can this be removed but keep the mapping for the rest of the year, so the graph is dynamic?

[image]

Comment: I should add, I have created a dynamic chart with one years worth of data. Highlighting the pivot table and creating the chart allows me to import new data each week to the data tab and refresh the workbook to update the tables and charts. But I can't add any more series to the chart as it is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get a chart that updates automatically is to convert all of your data to a table (select your current table, go to the ribbon > Table, select "New"). Then have your chart read the data from the new table, and it will automatically update any new data points that are added, no need to manually adjust the data being grabbed each week. You just pull down the bottom right corner of the new table, and it incorporates the new data, and sends it to the chart.

That will take care of all the static information. This next step will take care of the dynamic data, might get a little tricky.

Basically, set up the next rows in the table to read directly from the pivot table (fill in the cell to say "=b20", "=c20", etc). If there's no data for a particular week, you'll have to either manually drag the new formula down week by week, filling in the table as you go (which, helpfully, will continue updating the chart)... or you can maybe try something with an "=iferror" function, where it fills in a "" if the cell is empty. Not so certain about that last option, but it's worth a try.

Let me know you need any clarification!

Comment: I should add, I have created a dynamic chart with one years worth of data. Highlighting the pivot table and creating the chart allows me to import new data each week to the data tab and refresh the workbook to update the tables and charts. But I can't add any more series to the chart as it is greyed out.

Comment: Have tried what you suggested, has worked up until the last step. When i add "iferror" function with blank ("") as a value it leaves a line on the graph at 0. Any ideas how to remove the line for the future dates on the chart?